# How to send multiple URLs simultaneously with PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I wanted to send different url at same time.this is the code which i used.Can you please tell me the error in here?

```
<?php
    $data = R::find('savedata','list_name = ? order by id desc',array($i));

    foreach ( $data as $list):
        $mh = curl_multi_init(); //set up a cURL multiple execution handle
        $ch = curl_init("https://example.com/save_data.php?NUM=$list->id&MSG=$message"); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);           
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch); 
    endforeach; 

    curl_multi_exec($mh,);                          
    curl_multi_close($mh)
?>
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Firstly - what does `$data` look like? Secondly, you have a floating comma in `curl_multi_exec`. Thirdly, are you sure that your URL's are correct and that the class variables expand? Fourthly, where does `$message` come from? Fifthly, you're initializing `curl_multi_init` for every single iteration - this should only be done once.

Comment: Here I wanted to send several url at same time.I tried using several methods but they didn't work.@h2ooooooo the Url is correct.

Comment: @ Theolodies- I didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all.I have corrected this by my self.I am sharing the correct code with you,

$mobile = R::find('add_numbers', 'list_name = ? order by id desc', array($i));

```
foreach ($mobile as $list):
    try{
  $url = "https://example.com/save_data.php?NUM=$list->id&MSG=****";
    $ch = curl_init($url);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // TRUE
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   $results = curl_exec($ch);
     $i[]=$results;
    }
```